Error execute script to export py to .exe
I have a problem wanting to convert a tkinker app from py to .exe.
It should be noted that I am using an image recognition model, especially layoutparser-0.0.0-py3-none-any.
I ran the auto-py-to-exe in a virtual environment with all the libraries the same as my virtual environment to create the exe.
However, I get this error in the image
enter image description here
I hope you can help me.
It seems strange to me, since at no time do I make calls to lyric resources, to give an example.
